# How to find the subnet mask of the Azure Public IP?

Tags: networking, azure

We are trying to setup a site to site VPN with the Azure. We are using Ubiquiti device on our end. On Ubiquiti device it asks for the Remote Network IP and the Subnet Mask, where do I find the subnet mask for the Azure Public IP ?

Azure Public IP: 51.141.xx.xx

**Get-AzPublicIpAddress** command doesnt show the subnet mask.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

To tell your mask, the complete IP Address is required. Here is the list of all Azure subnets - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519

Answer (score 1):

You must be reading the page incorrectly.  The remote subnet is unknown to you, and doesn't affect your configuration in any way.  You only need the IP address.

Most likely, it is referring to  the subnet of the networks in the encryption domain (*i.e.*, the networks that pass through the VPN tunnel).  You should know those.

Or, it's referring to the subnet mask on your end.

Answer (score -1):

Would help if you shared a screenshot or some other info, but according to this guide it only asks for the azure subnet e.g 10.10.0.0/16 and not the gateway subnet

https://robertwray.co.uk/blog/creating-a-site-to-site-vpn-between-azure-and-a-ubiquiti-unifi-security-gateway-usg

> ```
>   Purpose: Site-to-Site VPN
>     VPN Type: Manual IPSec
>     Remote Subnets: Fill in the remote subnets that are in Azure here, so 10.2.0.0/16 as that's what I've configured
>     Peer IP: This is the IP from Azure, the one I ended up naming "unifi_vpn_gateway_ip" further up
>     Local WAN IP: This is the IP that the USG is establishing a VPN on, so will be the same IP specified when creating a "local network gateway" in Azure
> ```

Comment: Here is the screenshot from Ubiquiti on setting up vpn [link](https://i.imgur.com/viQrWWD.jpg)

Comment: @bickyz To me that looks like the remote subnet(s) in Azure, your internal vNET/subnet e.g. 10.10.10.10/24. and not the subnet of the public IP on the gateway.